# Contains string in columns, Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, string

I would like to know if a string is contained in a record or cell, my code is :

```
animals = [('The mouse is brown', 5, 'mouse'),
       ('The dog is green', np.NaN, 'dog'),
       ('The cat us blue', 10, 'cat'),
       ('The mouse is gray', 12, 'mouse'),
       ('The cow is white', np.NaN, 'cow'),
       ('The bull is brown', 3, 'bull'),
       ('The sheep is yellow', 20, np.NaN),
       (np.NaN, 8, 'parrot',),
       ('The horse is black', 4, 'mouse',),
       (np.NaN, np.NaN, np.NaN,)
        ]

df = pd.DataFrame(animals, columns =['Sentence', 'Quantity', 'Animal'],
                    index =['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', 
                            '6', '7', '8', '9', '10'])

    Sentence            Quantity    Animal
1   The mouse is brown   5.0        mouse
2   The dog is green     NaN        dog
3   The cat us blue      10.0       cat
4   The mouse is gray    12.0       mouse
5   The cow is white     NaN        cow
6   The bull is brown    3.0        bull
7   The sheep is yellow  20.0       NaN
8   NaN                  8.0        parrot
9   The horse is black   4.0        mouse
10  NaN                  NaN        NaN

def metProcces(strTemp):
    if ('mouse' in strTemp):
        return 'The mouse is catched'
    else:
        return 'NNN'

df['Sentence2'] = metProcces(df['Sentence'])

    Sentence           Quantity  Animal Sentence2
1   The mouse is brown  5.0      mouse  NNN
2   The dog is green    NaN      dog    NNN
3   The cat us blue     10.0     cat    NNN
4   The mouse is gray   12.0     mouse  NNN
5   The cow is white    NaN      cow    NNN
6   The bull is brown   3.0      bull   NNN
7   The sheep is yellow 20.0     NaN    NNN
8   NaN                 8.0      parrot NNN
9   The horse is black  4.0      mouse  NNN
10  NaN                 NaN      NaN    NNN
```

In the final dataset the column Sentence2 does not have the correct value for 'mouse' like in the method metProcess is defined, 'The mouse is catched'

Thanks for all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try via `str.contains()`:

```
c=df['Sentence'].str.contains('mouse').fillna(False)
#your condition
```

Finally:

```
df['Sentence2']=c.map({True:'The mouse is catched',False:'NNN'})
#OR
df['Sentence2']=c.replace({True:'The mouse is catched',False:'NNN'})
#OR
#import numpy as np
df['Sentence2']=np.where(c,'The mouse is catched','NNN')
```

Comment: So let me ask the initial question again. Now, how is your answer better than mine?

Comment: @paradocslover One problem can be solved using several approaches so you used `apply()` method I used `str.contains()`  as I don't prefer `apply()` in such cases so both are good at their own places and btw I didn't mention in my answer that my approach is better than your approach so why you asked  *'how is your answer better than mine?'*

Comment: It's not about who's better, it's about getting to learn more. You are using an extra space in the form of the `c` variable, so if both the approaches are serving the same purpose, mine should be better, right? And if there's something that i am missing than maybe you can point that out. At the end it's a tech-debate, so win-win for both.

Comment: @paradocslover it's not the debate if your answer is better than mine then I will surely admit that  and yes In that sence your answer is better(In terms of speed) but if I change my answer by removing `c` variable then `df['Sentence'].fillna('').map(lambda x:'The mouse is catched' if 'mouse' in x else 'NNN')` is faster than your method

Comment: @paradocslover but I will not update `df['Sentence'].fillna('').map(lambda x:'The mouse is catched' if 'mouse' in x else 'NNN')` in my answer to preserve originality so your method faster(In terms of speed) then mine ***:)***

Answer (score 1):

The issue in your `metProcces` function is that you are checking in the entire Series but what you need is to check in a particular record of the Series.

And for that you need `apply` function of pandas

```py
def sentence_processor(x):
    try:
        return 'The mouse is catched' if 'mouse' in x else 'NNN'
    except: #In NaN cases
        return 'NNN'

df['Sentence2'] = df['Sentence'].apply(sentence_processor)
```